# Flutter GeneratedPluginRegistrant: can't find android dependency for a plugin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, plugins, build.gradle

I wrote a Flutter plugin that find the absolute path for a file on an Android system using the [PickiT](https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT/i) library. The plugin, called [Flutter absolute path](https://gitlab.com/elRepo.io/flutter_absolute_path), has the dependency of the PickiT library added on the plugin [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/elRepo.io/flutter_absolute_path/-/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L32):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.HBiSoft:PickiT:2.0.5'
}
```

But when I add this plugin to my app and I try to compile it, I receive this error:

```
<APP_PATH>/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:34: error: cannot access PickiTCallbacks
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new net.altermundi.flutter_absolute_path.FlutterAbsolutePathPlugin());
                                ^
  class file for com.hbisoft.pickit.PickiTCallbacks not found
```

The only way that I found to make my plugin working is to add the library to my project on the `app/build.gradle` dependencies also.

How can I make the plugin Android dependency implicit on the whole project without adding it?